# BMI calculator in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and still trying to learn my way around it. Today my teacher gave an assignment where we make a BMI calculator in Java. One of the steps is to make it show the BMI categories. So the user would be able to look at it and see where they stand. I got everything else done but am running into an issue.

Here is the script:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double weight = 0.0;
        double height = 0.0;
        double bmi = 0.0;

        System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
        weight = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your height: ");
        height = input.nextInt();

        bmi = ((weight * 703)/(height * height));

        System.out.printf("Your BMI is", bmi);

        System.out.println("BMI VALUES");
        System.out.println("Underweight: Under 18.5");
        System.out.println("Normal: 18.5-24.9 ");
        System.out.println("Overweight: 25-29.9");
        System.out.println("Obese: 30 or over");
     }
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
Your BMI isBMI VALUES
Underweight: Under 18.5
Normal: 18.5-24.9 
Overweight: 25-29.9
Obese: 30 or over
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 13):

You forgot the placeholder for the `bmi` (and the line terminator):

```
System.out.printf("Your BMI is %f\n", bmi);
```

Here's the [formatting syntax guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for your reference.

Comment: (btw, `bmi` appears to be a `double`, not an `int`.)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("Your BMI is %f\n", bmi);
```

You can also print like this:

```
System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi);
```

Comment: @ThatOneDude - if it solved your problem, you should click the checkmark for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

While you are using `printf`, the following also works:

```
System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should print floats / doubles in a readable format Normally BMI value is measured up to 2 decimal place

```
System.out.format("Your BMI is %.2f%n",bmi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] ht = new double[5];
    double[] wt = new double[5];
    double[] bmi = new double[5];
    String[] sht = new String[5];
    String[] swt = new String[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
        sht[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Hight");
        swt[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Weight");
        ht[i]=Double.parseDouble(sht[i]);
        wt[i]=Double.parseDouble(swt[i]);
        bmi[i]=wt[i]/(ht[i]*ht[i]);
        System.out.println("BMI IS "+bmi[i]+"Kg/m2");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"BMI IS  "+bmi[i] +"Kg/m2");
        if(bmi[i]>25){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOU ARE AT RISK");
            System.out.println("YOU ARE AT RISK");
        }else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"YOU ARE Healthy"); 
           System.out.println("YOU ARE Healthy ");
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more coding but you could use JOptionPane

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is you weight in pounds?");
        weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your hight is inches?");
        height = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

mismatch between variable type declaration (double) and your declaration of user input type (nextInt)
I would use nextDouble as an input type if you want to maintain variable type as a double.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arghadasofficial/BMI/blob/master/src/argha/bmi/Bmi.java

```
public class Bmi {

    //Variables
    private double result; //Stores the result
    private String bmi; //Stores the Bmi result in String
    private String status; //Stores the status (Normal......)
    private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".#"); //Formating the result

    /**
     * Get the BMI from calculation and returns the result in String format
     *
     * @return BMI
     */
    public String getBmi() {
        /**
         * Following code example : bmi = decimalFormat.format(result);
         *
         * if bmi is 23.12345 then remove 2345 and return 23.1 using DecimalFormat class provided by Java
         *
         */
        bmi = decimalFormat.format(result);
        return bmi;
    }

    /**
     * Get the status according to the BMI result and returns the Status in
     * String format
     *
     * @return Status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Get weight and height in double format and do the calculation for you
     *
     * @param weight - accepts weight in kilograms
     * @param height - accept height in centimeters
     */
    public void calculateBmi(double weight, double height) {
        /**
         * First get weight and height then convert height to meters then
         * multiply the height itself to height and then divide the height with
         * weight then set the actual value to result variable
         */

        //Convert the height from cm to m
        double meters = height / 100;

        //Multiply height by height
        double multiply = meters * meters;

        //divide the height with weight in kg
        double division = weight / multiply;

        //set the value to result variable
        result = division;

        //call checkStatus method for checking Status
        checkStatus();
    }

    /**
     * Private method for checking bmi and returns the status It remains private
     * because we don't need to access this from somewhere else.
     */
    private void checkStatus() {
        /**
         * Check :
         *
         * if BMI is less than 18.5 then set status to Underweight if BMI is
         * greater than 18.5 and less than 25 then set status to Normal if BMI
         * is greater than 25 and less than 30 then set status to Overweight if
         * BMI equals to 30 or greater than 30 then set status to Obese
         */
        if (result < 18.5) {
            status = "Underweight";
        } else if (result > 18.5 && result < 25) {
            status = "Normal";
        } else if (result > 25 && result < 30) {
            status = "Overweight";
        } else if (result == 30 || result > 30) {
            status = "Obese";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Consider expanding your answer by explaining how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Bmi bmi = new Bmi();
 bmi.calculateBmi(65, 162);
 System.out.println(bmi.getBmi());
 System.out.println(bmi.getStatus());

Comment: Excellent, consider [edit]ing  your post and adding that explanation.

Answer (score -2):

A: I am not sure that `bmi = ((weight * 703)/(height * height));` is right.

I came across a formula which might work for you 
      `BMI = ((weight/(height * height))* 10000;`

B:   `System.out.printf(“Your BMI is”, bmi);` is not needed 
      `System.out.prinln( “ Your BMI is “ + BMI);`

I hope it work for you 
best of luck keep it up